# Do I have to override every function in base class, if I want to change the return type of a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an abstract class A that returns a pointer of its type. Then I have a derived class B which implements the methods defined in class A. I want the methods defined in class B to return class B pointers. Any idea how to do that?

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual A* foo() {}
}
class B: public A {}

B *x = new B();
x->foo();  // This should return B*
```

Do I need to override foo in B to return B*? Is there some better way ?

Comment: @NicolBolas corrected it

Comment: The trick is to use "covariant return type".

Answer (score 5):

I can think of 2 ways to achieve that:

#### 1. Overriding (requires `foo` to be virtual)

This can only be done if the return types are covariant, but if B inherits from A then B is covariant to A.

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual A* foo() { return new A; }
};
class B: public A {
    public:
        B* foo() override { return new B; }
};
```

#### 2. [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) (CRTP)

You can provide child class as template parameter for the base class.

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
        T* foo() { return new T; }
};
class B: public A<B> {
    // only B* foo() exists
};
```

Comment: In the case of CRTP you probably also need an additional non-template base class from which `A` inherits. Otherwise, without a common base type, there is no benefit to inheritance or polymorphism and they should just use `B` directly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This is interesting.  Do you have an example where the CRTP class inherits from a common base class?

Comment: @shargors Not off hand. It's hard enough to invent a plausible use case for CRTP on the spot, it is harder to come up with a plausible use case for that *and* additional requirements. But it is necessary if various specializations are expected to used polymorphically.

Comment: Will CRTP work for multilevel inheritance  A -> B -> C. ?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Will CRTP work for multilevel inheritance A -> B -> C. ?